# Show only author comment on them wordpress dashboard

Tags: wordpress, comments

I got this code from somewhere here to show only author's comment in dashboard. But its not even showing any single comment or the author post on author dashboard.

Please help me to correct it.

```
function my_plugin_get_comment_list_by_user($clauses) { if (is_admin()) { global $user_ID, $wpdb; $clauses['join'] = ", wp_posts"; $clauses['where'] .= " AND wp_posts.post_author = ".$user_ID." AND wp_comments.comment_post_ID = wp_posts.ID"; }; return $clauses; }; // Ensure that editors and admins can moderate all comments if(!current_user_can('edit_others_posts')) { add_filter('comments_clauses', 'my_plugin_get_comment_list_by_user'); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this by some customizations :

```
<?php
  $my_id = 7;
  $comment_id_7 = get_comment( $my_id, ARRAY_A );
  $name = $comment_id_7['comment_author'];
?>
```

alse use this :

```
<div class="commentlist"><?php wp_list_comments(array('style' => 'div')); ?></div>
```

Comment: May be its my mistake I didn't post entire code.. Here is full code. I am looking for dashboard comment section and not for front end. This code is for show author's post comment on Dashboard Comment section. So author can see only his/her post comment and can moderate as well. However bu using below code its disappear all comments even if author's own post comment.

Comment: Here is the code what I am using...


`function my_plugin_get_comment_list_by_user($clauses) {
if (is_admin()) {
    global $user_ID, $wpdb;
    $clauses['join'] = ", wp_posts";
    $clauses['where'] .= " AND wp_posts.post_author = ".$user_ID." AND wp_comments.comment_post_ID = wp_posts.ID";
};
return $clauses;
};
// Ensure that editors and admins can moderate all comments
if(!current_user_can('edit_others_posts')) {
add_filter('comments_clauses', 'my_plugin_get_comment_list_by_user');
}`